# How to parameter field when parameter is null

Tags: jasper-reports

I have created 2 parameter `$P{SEC_NAME}` and `$P{AGENCY_CODE}`. Then i want to display **"NONE"** when `$P{SEC_NAME}` parameter key in nothing.

I have tried this code at **PrintWhenExpression**:
`new Boolean ($P{SEC_NAME} != null? $P{SEC_NAME}:"None")`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: It is not the `PrintWhenExpression`, it is the `textFieldExpression`

Comment: Ok thanks Alex K. It work when I paste the expression at textFieldExpression

Comment: @Alex Why not add that as an answer to the question so Rozie can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The ***printWhenExpression*** property is used for determine to show a report element (`textField`, for example) or not.

In your case you should use ***textFieldExpression*** property for displaying expression.

The sample for displaying the string with *'None'* value in case when the parameter's value is not defined (check for ***null***):

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="100" y="24" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{SEC_NAME} != null ? $P{SEC_NAME} : "None"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```